# Run publisher in a separate callback like function

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to have a callback function similar to that of subscribers to run a function that publishes to a topic at regular intervals? I guess it could be done anyway with threading but is there something already available to handle this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374240/run-publisher-in-a-separate-callback-like-function/) by [omkar_a_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/58173/omkar_a_k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you asking about [timers](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omkar_a_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/58173/omkar_a_k/) on 2021-03-18**:
This is what I was looking for.